# Cannot access nested routes directly with vue-router and Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I am using vue-router 3 with Laravel 8 behind nginx. (Everything is containerized in Docker, but will omit for this question) The problem is that I can access top-level URLs directly, but not sub-level URLs. I can only access the sub-level URLs by clicking a `<router-link>`. As specified in the vue-router documentation, when using `mode: history`, there should be a catch-all route. I implemented one in Laravel, but it still does not seem to be working correctly.

nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/;
    server_name localhost;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    default_type text/html;

    location /publications/public/ {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /publications/public/index.php?$args;
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass publications:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }
    }
}
```

router.js

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/login',
        component: Login
    },
    {
        path: '/admin',
        component: Admin,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'edit',
                component: Edit
            }
        ]
    }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: '/publications/public/',
    routes: routes,
})
```

Admin component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-app>
            Admin page
            <v-btn @click="logout">Logout</v-btn>
            <router-link to="/admin/edit">/admin/edit</router-link>
            <router-view></router-view>
        </v-app>
    </div>
</template>
```

The catch-all in `web.php`

```
Route::get('{any}', function () {
    return view('app');
})->where('any', '^(?!/api).*$');
```

I can access `/login` directly on the browser. I can also directly access `/admin`, and can access `/admin/edit` only by clicking on the `<router-link>`. But I **cannot** access `/admin/edit` directly.

Going deeper it seems that `public/js/app.js` isn't being loaded properly (or not finding it) unlike in the top-level URLs. How can I fix this issue?

Edit: It seems the issue is that its searching `/public/admin/js` for `app.js` instead of `/public/js`.

Comment: `base: '/publications/public/',` to `base: '/publications/',`

Comment: @KamleshPaul Thanks for the advice, but unfortunately it did not work in my case. I did find the issue which I put in my edit post.

Comment: where your including `app.js` ? show that code

Comment: thank you this question was helpful

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue! The issue was that in my blade template, I had
`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>`. I changed this to `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/js/app.js') }}"></script>` to get the correct path to the `app.js` file.